# Is bosonic normal-ordering equal to fermionic normal ordering?

Tags: operators, wick-theorem, bosonization

I'm trying to understand Jan von Delft's "Bosonization for Beginners — Refermionization for Experts", in which he uses boson normal ordering and fermion normal ordering interchangeably, and I can't quite see why. Indeed, let $A_1,...,A_n$ be formal sums of the finite products of bosonic operators (free algebra generated by bosonic operators $b_q^*,b_q$), then I will denote the normal order with respect to bosons by
$$
N_B(A_1\cdots A_n).
$$
(The product is defined in the sense of the free algebra). Similarly, each $A_i$ must be an even in terms of fermion operators and thus there must be a corresponding fermion normal ordering, i.e.,
$$
N_F(A_1\cdots A_n)
$$
Now it should be such that the 2 are equal, but I don't think the justification given is sufficient. Indeed, in Eq. (21), the author claims that
$$
N_B(A_1\cdots A_n)=A_1\cdots A_n-\langle A_1\cdots A_n\rangle
$$
Where $\langle \cdots\rangle$ is with respect to the "vacuum state" (no particle-holes). I don't think this is true in general (it should only hold for $n=2$). Indeed, one can easily check that rather we should
$$
A_1\cdots A_n =\sum_{\text{all possible contractions}} N_B(\underbrace{A_1\cdots A_n}).
$$
Or conversely,
$$
N_B(A_1\cdots A_n)=\sum_{\text{all possible subsets } I} \langle\prod_{i\in I}A_i\rangle \prod_{j\notin I}A_j.
$$
So I'm a bit stuck on why $N_B=N_F$. Any help would be appreciated.